# Standalone/Domain Model not available in Infinispan server 10 and 11 version

Tags: caching, infinispan, infinispan-9, infinispan-8, redhat-datagrid

We are planning to setup infinispan server cluster setup in domain mode for infinispan server 10 or 11 version.

Standalone/Domain Model was available in Infinispan server until version 9.

Infinispan server 10/11 setup guide does not discuss anything about domain model.

Can anyone please confirm if domain mode is no longer supported in latest infinispan servers ?

Thanks,

Santhosh S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has been replaced with a completely redesigned server which is more suited to modern containerised deployments. Which features of domain mode did you want to leverage?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. I am not looking at any specific features from domain mode.

We have been using Jboss EAP application server in domain mode, so when we went to infinispan , we thought of following the similar setup.